# Maclaurin series to evaluate $\sqrt{1.2}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, radicals

How do I evaluate $\sqrt{1.2}$ using the Maclaurin series?

I tried using the general form of Maclaurin series but I can't get a correct answer, all the derivatives are 0.

Comment: McLaurin works on functions. What is your function here ?

Comment: As you have noticed, your question had several downvotes and [clove votes](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/721382). One of the reason for downvotes might be that the questions on this site are supposed to [include context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and yours does not. I suppose that you could substantially improve your question by elaborating on this: "I tried using the general form of Maclaurin series but I can't get a correct answer, all the derivatives are 0." (What is *general form of Maclaurin series*? What exactly were your computations?)

Answer (score 4):

$$\sqrt{1.2}=\sqrt{1.21-0.01}$$

$$1.1\sqrt{1-\frac{0.01}{1.21}}$$

and now expand $\sqrt{1+x}$ with $x=\frac{-1}{121}$ to get a better precision.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. From the Maclaurin series expansion
$$
f(x)=f(0)+\frac {f'(0)}{1!} x+ \frac{f''(0)}{2!} x^2+\frac{f^{(3)}(0)}{3!}x^3+ \cdots,
$$ one gets, for  $x$ near $0$,
$$
f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{x^3}{16}+O(x^4)
$$ then one may put $x=0.2$ in the above identity.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
use the function $y=\sqrt{1+x}$ to find the Maclaurin series and then let $x=0.2$

Answer (score 1):

According to the binomial expansion theorem:

$$(1+0.2)^{1/2}=1+\frac{0.2}2-\frac{0.2^2}8+\frac{0.2^3}{16}-\mathcal O(0.2^4)$$

Comment: Note that this isn't a Maclauran series... but an alternative way of answering the question

Comment: @SkeletonBow Techniquely generalized binomial expansion is a Taylor series, just for binomials.